# Merging data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Working with Excel files that contain over 3000 columns, and having an issue that there are several column headers that are duplicated. When this data is fed into another system it errors out. Looking for a way to merge the columns in the spreadsheet. Same header can appear in two to six columns, but each row of data only populates a single column.

I have seen one post that merges the column headers of the duplicates are next to each other, and I can do this (as I have in my sample data), but that post only merges the header data.

Not sure how to attach sample data, but hope people can see this:

```
1350725  1350725  1350740  1350813  1351468 1351468
B                          A        C
         A        C        B                E
C                 D        C        E  
A                 C        C        D
B                          E                B
```

Comment: Are some of the column headers duplicated more than once? Are duplicated headers always adjacent to each other? And also, how many rows would the longest column have?

Comment: My money is on PowerQuery for this challenge. Writing robust VBA is hard. Doing this with PowerQuery is so easy it borders on trivial. It might be slightly slower on a very large data set - particularly when compared against a Dictionary approach such as Ron Rosenfield's great approach, but it is simple to the point that a non VBA developer can pick up the basics of PowerQuery in mere hours and often the basics is all you need to do something that would otherwise require quite advanced VBA. And it takes years for a non VBA developer to become a VBA developer.

Comment: So did you end up using any of the below approaches?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with **Power query**. It is an add-in for Excel 2010+ (by default in Excel 2016 known as Get & Transform). There you can connect directly Excel with any source of data and then transform the data in the Query Editor. For your case follow this steps:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this should work.
I use a dictionary storing arrays to dedupe the columns.
Note that you MUST set a reference as in the comments (or make some small changes to use late-binding).  And also you will need to change the source and results worksheet names to align with your data.

Furthermore, an assumption is that the source data table is the only thing on this worksheet, and it starts in `A1`.  The `LastRowCol` function detects the end point of the data.

If your source data table does not meet these requirements, changes will need to be made to detect the correct data area.

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub CombineColumns()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim dD As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim lLastRowCol() As Long
    Dim V() As Variant

'set Source and REsults worksheets, ranges
 Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet5")
 Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet6")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'Get source data into vba array
With wsSrc
    lLastRowCol = LastRowCol(wsSrc.Name)
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lLastRowCol(0), lLastRowCol(1)))
End With

'Collect and merge the data
Set dD = New Dictionary
ReDim V(2 To UBound(vSrc, 1))
For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
    If Not dD.Exists(vSrc(1, J)) Then 'set new dictionary item
        For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
            V(I) = vSrc(I, J)
        Next I
        dD.Add Key:=vSrc(1, J), Item:=V
    Else 'combine the columns
        For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
            If vSrc(I, J) <> "" Then
                V = dD(vSrc(1, J))
                V(I) = vSrc(I, J)
                dD(vSrc(1, J)) = V
            End If
        Next I
    End If
Next J

'Write results to output array
ReDim vRes(0 To UBound(vSrc, 1) - 1, 1 To dD.Count)

'Headers
J = 0
Dim V1 As Variant
For Each V1 In dD.Keys
    J = J + 1
    vRes(0, J) = V1
Next V1

'Data
For J = 1 To UBound(vRes, 2)
    I = 0
    For Each V1 In dD(vRes(0, J))
        I = I + 1
        vRes(I, J) = V1
    Next V1
Next J

'write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub

Private Function LastRowCol(Worksht As String) As Long()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim L(1) As Long
Set WS = Worksheets(Worksht)
With WS
    Set R = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = R.Row
        LastCol = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Else
        LastRow = 1
        LastCol = 1
    End If
End With

L(0) = LastRow
L(1) = LastCol
LastRowCol = L
End Function
```

**Original Data**

[image]

**Combined**

[image]

Comment: This is really clever, Ron. Probably only thing I would change is go with late bound to avoid the need to set a reference. But I like your approach!

Comment: @jeffreyweir Thanks.  I generally prefer early-binding as it is a bit more efficient, usually enables intellisense, and also shows the reference in the Object Browser. For me, this makes code development easier.  For distribution, and sometimes to maintain changing reference issues, late-binding certainly has an advantage.  It's trivial to change the above code to incorporate late-binding.

Answer (score 0):

PowerQuery is by far the best tool for this, because you can whip together a solution in mere minutes without expending too much brain power.

But for completeness, here's a VBA solution that will do what you want, and that also handles more than two duplicate columns. It assumes these columns will always be located alongside, as with your sample data.

This took me between 30mins and 60mins to put together and troubleshoot, because I was trying to optimize and dealing with columns you delete takes a bit of thought. By contrast, putting together a solution in PQ probably would have taken me mere minutes. That's why I voted for the approach that @virtualdvid took. And in terms of efficiency and robustness, my approach isn't as fast or robust as Rick's Dictionary approach below. This horse would come in a distant third compared to PQ or Dictionary.

```
Sub Test()

Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim lLastCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim sHeader1 As String
Dim sHeader2 As String

lLastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = lLastCol To 1 Step -1
    sHeader1 = Cells(1, i)
    For j = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
        sHeader2 = Cells(1, j)
        If sHeader2 <> sHeader1 Then Exit For
        If sHeader1 = sHeader2 Then
            lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            For k = 2 To lLastRow
                If Cells(k, i).Value <> "" Then
                    Cells(k, j).Value = Cells(k, i).Value
                End If
            Next k
            Columns(i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Note that this is not optimal VBA. You can optimize this further by turning off screenupdating. Even better, don't bother doing that but instead pull ALL the data into VBA in one go in a Variant Array, do the consolidation there using similar code, then dump it back into the worksheet in one go. And even better than that would be a Dictionary approach similar to Ricks.

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To lastcol
    For j = i To lastcol
        If Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(1, j).Value And i <> j Then 'Merge em
            lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            lastrow2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row

            If lastrow < lastrow2 Then
                lastrow = lastrow2
            End If

                For k = 2 To lastrow
                    If Cells(k, j).Value <> "" Then
                        Cells(k, i).Value = Cells(k, j).Value
                    End If
                Next k

                Columns(j).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Test data:

[image: TestData]

On your test data:

[image: TestData2]

Not sure why my picture isn't coming through... Sorry about that. EDIT: Looks like it's working now.

Comment: Did not work, that deleted some of the columns with duplicate header names, but did not merge any of the data prior to deletion. Still have (some) duplicate headers as well.

Comment: @BrentOliver Works fine on my sample data and the data you posted as well, no issues here - something is different in your actual data than from what you've posted - Are your headers in row 1, data beginning in column A?

Comment: @BrentOliver I can see that one issue is how I'm getting the last row of data, but that should still merge in 90% of it.

Comment: The data in columns A-W is identifying data for the row in question. Columns X on are as shown in sample data. Just removed A-W and reran. Deleted more data, but nothing merged. Real data has large amount of blank cells (either 150 or 200 cells on each row of over 3000 is populated.

Comment: @BrentOliver I can't do much more for you with what you've given me to work with - If it works on your sample data but not on your actual worksheet, then your sample data is not a true depiction of your real data.

Comment: @dwirony Perhaps the issue is due to more than one duplicate column, plus duplicate columns not always being located adjacent to each other, as per my question above.

Comment: @dwirony There's a couple of issues with your code as written. First, when deleting columns in a loop you need to work from right to left and use a negative step. Otherwise your code will skip the column that just took the place of the one you just deleted. Second, your line If lastrow < lastrow2 should be If lastrow > lastrow2 (This doesn't effect output, but is just an efficiency thing). There's a couple more changes I'd make, and I might post a rewrite shortly to demonstrate.

Comment: @jeffreyweir The poster gave minimal data to work with so I assumed here could only be 2 columns (1 duplicate). In that case, I don't need to step backwards through my loop because it wouldn't matter. I see the efficiency part that you're talking about regarding lastrow, but the output is the same so I'm not worried about it.

Comment: Point taken: if your assumptions were correct, no need for negative loop. That's the problem with working off requirements derived from sample data. I think the OP did a reasonable job of providing starter-for-10 sample data...but they don't know what you need to know for this specific approach. Whereas the other two approaches (PQ, Dictionary) didn't need anything more from the OP: they are both robust to multiple columns and don't even care about column order. But gotta say your comment that your not "worried" about efficiency has me scratching my head. Isn't that what we strive for?

Comment: @jeffreyweir The assignment of value to `lastrow` would be so minimal that no one would ever notice that kind of difference... It completely depends on the kind of efficiency we're talking about here.

Comment: So what "other" types of efficiency are there?